# Removing the KDE line while keeping the density plot histogram in Seaborns `distplot`

Tags: python, data-visualization, seaborn

```
import seaborn as sns, numpy as np
x = np.random.randn(100)
ax = sns.distplot(x)
```

This will give a density histogram with a line (I think it is the kernel fit or something)

However I want the SAME histogram but not the fitted line. I have tried with `kde = False` but this changes the y-axis so it is not longer a density plot but frequency histogram. **How do I remove the line but keep the density plot (histogram)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the kernel density estimate (kde) line by accessing the line objects from the axis object `ax` as following. This way, you still retain the density plot.

```
import seaborn as sns, numpy as np
x = np.random.randn(100)
ax = sns.distplot(x)

ax.get_lines()[0].remove()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*Full docs [here](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html)*

The best way to remove this line is

```
import seaborn as sns, numpy as np
x = np.random.randn(100)

# Without the KDE line present, the bars will represent raw counts, not frequencies
ax = sns.distplot(x, kde=False)

# To plot frequencies (normalize the histogram), set the norm_hist argument to true
ax = sns.distplot(x, kde=False, norm_hist=True)
```

Both of these plot the bins without the KDE line. (Note that without the KDE line, the x-range of your graph will be slightly narrower.) If you'd wanted just the line and no bars, you could do `ax = sns.distplot(x, hist=False)`.